# Where can I find the location of view, edit, delete button in Yii2?

Tags: yii, yii2

I want to delete the view, edit, delete's button. But I cant find where the location. The buttons are like the picture below:

[image]
https://ibb.co/eiXnpa

Where can I find the location of view, edit, delete button in Yii2? I want to edit the code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can hide those three as follows
1.Go to your views folder
2.find your folder name(same as that of table name)
3.now open the folder and find the index.php 
 and the code will look like below code,and use // to hide the column.Just add // before  ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'] as i have shown in the code.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'username',
         'Address',
         'Head',
         'mobile',
        'school',
        'manager',

        // ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [CRUD Generator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html#generating-crud), you could edit your `index` view as below

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        // ...

        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'visibleButtons' => [
                'update' => FALSE,
                'delete' => FALSE,
                'view' => FALSE
            ]
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

There is another way,

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        // ...

        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',

            //  Only display `delete` button.
            'template' => '{delete}',
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```